# Base url for routers does not show up in browserable api with hyperlinked model serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework, router, django-urls

Some code first:
**serializers.py**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model  = Post
      fields = '__all__'

class CommentSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model  = Comment
      fields = '__all__'
```

In **viewsets.py** i just use a model viewset and a queryset for all the objects.
Now in my **api.urls**, the routers are registered like so:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register('posts', PostViewSet)    
router.register('comments', CommentViewSet) 

# this is what i want
urlpatterns = [
   re_path(r'api/', include(router.urls),

]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

As you can see, the base url for the routers is *api/*.
When i go to localhost:8000/api/comments/, i get the correct output.
But then in the comment list, for a particular comment, i get

```
{
   "url": "localhost:8000/comments/1/",
   "post": "localhost:8000/posts/1/"
}
```

Notice the absent base url (api/)..
Instead i expect

```
{
   "url": "localhost:8000/api/comments/1/",
   "post": "localhost:8000/api/posts/1/"
}
```

Also, if i go to either *localhost:8000/api/commnets/1/* or *localhost:8000/comments/1/*, i get the correct individual comment.

My question boils down to *why is the api/ missing from the url in the browserable api and how to solve it.*

Answer (score -1):

In my app's urls.py,

I changed path(' ', include('app_name.api.urls')) to path('api/', include('app_name.api.urls'))

Then in api.urls, changed re_path (r 'api/ ', include(router.urls)) to path (' ', include(router.urls))